# Unable to see FOSCAM FI9831P streaming in ZoneMinder

Tags: zoneminder

I've been trying to set up ZoneMinder to be able to see streamed video from a FOSCAM FI9831P.

I've successfully tested the camera using VLC for the following url: rtsp://username:password@IPADDRESS:88/videoMain

Unfortunately I haven't been able to use this configuration in zoneminder, i.e:

```
Source Type: Remote 
Remote Protocol: RTSP 
Remote Method: RTP/Unicast 
Remote Host Name: IPADDRESS 
Remote Host Port: 88 Remote Host 
Path: /videoMain 
Target Colorspace: 32 bits 
Capture Width: 1280 
Capture Height: 720
```

I always get the same errors:

```
2015-07-23 19:53:32.002350  zmdc    9974    ERR 'zmc -m 1' exited abnormally, exit status 255   zmdc.pl 
2015-07-23 19:53:31.999636  zmc_m1  10322   FAT No RTSP sources zm_remote_camera_rtsp.cpp   155
2015-07-23 19:53:22.911336  zmc_m1  10326   ERR Unexpected response code 400, text is 'Bad Request' zm_rtsp.cpp 92
2015-07-23 19:53:22.903196  zmc_m1  10326   ERR Unexpected response code 401, text is 'Unauthorized'    zm_rtsp.cpp 92
```

Now, taking into consideration that I'm able to use VLC, it should not be a connection problem to the came itself... so I'm guessing Apache faulty configuration. I just can't put my finger on it!